# Getting blank statement in django model charfield with mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-database

I just migrated my django application from sqlite3 to mysql 5.1.41. I have a charfield in a model defined like this:

```
class HostData(models.Model):
  Host = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
  HostStatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  Alarm = models.BooleanField()
```

Everything works the same except HostStatus, which usually returns a string like "Up, waiting". In mysql, however, it is blank. I created my table with character set to utf-8. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there data actually in the table?

Comment: when querying the table, there is data in the other fields, except in HostStatus. I get the data from an array, which is non-empty (contains the "Up, waiting" string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the way I was assigning the value to the model. I dont know why it worked well in sqlite, but it was bad coding anyways. This is what I was doing:

```
myarray = stdout_ssh
myobject = test.object.get(id=3)
myobject.Host = stdout_ssh[0]
myobject.HostStatus = status
status = stdout_ssh[1]
myobject.Alarm = False
myobject.save()
```

I changed this to:

```
myarray = stdout_ssh
myobject = test.object.get(id=3)
myobject.Host = stdout_ssh[0]
myobject.HostStatus = stdout_ssh[1]
myobject.Alarm = False
myobject.save()
```

And everything was ok.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with that model code.

How have you migrated your data over to MySQL?  When you enter data via the django admin, does it enter data into the db?

If a view is entering this data, can you post the view code.

Comment: Thanks for your input Stuart. I found the issue which is described in my answer.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you figured it out.